# GZIP file Total length in C#

Tags: c#, gzip, gunzip

I have a zipped file having size of several GBs, I want to get the size of Unzipped contents but don't want to actually unzip the file in C#, What might be the Library I can use? When I right click on the .gz file and go to Properties then under the `Archive` Tab there is a property name `TotalLength` which is showing this value. But I want to get it Programmatically using C#.. Any idea?

Comment: The info might be present in the gzip header. But I can't help more than that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The last 4 bytes of the gz file contains the length.

So it should be something like:

```
using(var fs = File.OpenRead(path))
{
  fs.Position = fs.Length - 4;
  var b = new byte[4];
  fs.Read(b, 0, 4);
  uint length = BitConverter.ToUInt32(b, 0);
  Console.WriteLine(length);
}
```

Comment: ah, much better; I'm not sure how this is handled when >4GB though

Comment: Thanks Leppie... actually in my case the file will be less than 4GB... Thanks for your help...

Comment: @leppie no problem, thank _you_ for the great answer.

Answer (score 4):

The last for bytes of a .gz file are the uncompressed input size modulo 2^32. If your uncompressed file isn't larger than 4GB, just read the last 4 bytes of the file. If you have a larger file, I'm not sure that it's possible to get without uncompressing the stream.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: See the answers by Leppie and Gabe; the only reason I'm keeping this (rather than deleting it) is that it may be necessary if you suspect the length is > 4GB

---

For gzip, that data doesn't seem to be directly available - I've looked at `GZipStream` and the [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/) equivalent - neither works. The best I can suggest is to run it locally:

```
    long length = 0;
    using(var fs = File.OpenRead(path))
    using (var gzip = new GZipStream(fs, CompressionMode.Decompress)) {
        var buffer = new byte[10240];
        int count;
        while ((count = gzip.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0) {
            length += count;
        }
    }
```

If it was a zip, then SharpZipLib:

```
    long size = 0;
    using(var zip = new ZipFile(path)) {
        foreach (ZipEntry entry in zip) {
            size += entry.Size;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Marc, the first method worked for me.. but its taking too long to calculate a 2 GB uncompressed file... and it should be as we are counting in loop... Isn't there any quick way?

Comment: @Ummar: Both Gabe and myself explained the 'correct' way of doing this. The above way will work, but imagine using it on 1000's of 2GB files, it will take forever.

Answer (score -2):

```
public static long mGetFileLength(string strFilePath)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strFilePath))
    {
        System.IO.FileInfo info = new System.IO.FileInfo(strFilePath);
        return info.Length;
    }

    return 0; 
}
```